# Keep date from updating everyday?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a table that stores tasks and elements such as Date Completed. I have a button on the table that marks the task completed and it updates the table with the Date Completed column with the current date. If I click the button to mark the task as completed the day, it will put 2/2/2018. The problem is, when I load the table tomorrow, it will automatically update the date to 2/3/2018. How do I prevent this from happening and keep the original date? When I build the table, items[i].completed_date is input for %dateCompleted%.

HTML:

```
<tr class="rowTable dropdown-button" data-id="%todoID%" data-activates="todo_dropdown" data-context="true" data-type="edit-%canedit%" data-canedit="%canedit%" data-constrainwidth="false">
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox" data-complete="%notTrue%" data-show="hidden">
      <div class="todo_checkbox"></div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>%todoTitle%</td>
  <td>%resources%</td>
  <td class="%isOverdue%">%duedate%</td>
  <td>%percentcomplete%</td>
  <td class="completedCalendar">%dateCompleted%</td>
  <td>
    <div class="button">
      <img id="optionsButton" src="/app/images/master/actions_btn.svg" />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (completed) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id == itemsID) {
      var itemsID = items[i].id;
      items[i].progress = 100;
      container.find(".checkbox").attr('data-complete', 'false');
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].progress == 100) {
          var completed = new Date();
          items[i].completed_date = completed.toLocaleDateString();
        }
        if (items[i].progress != 100) {
          items[i].completed_date = "";
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `new Date()` will always return the current date and time

Comment: `if (items[i].progress == 100 && !items[i].completed_date)` ... or something similar to also check not only whether the task is complete but also whether or not the completed date is empty or if it already has a previous value. Are you storing this in a database, or browser localStorage or something?

Comment: @mc01 Sorry for the late reponse but I am storing it in a database

Answer (score 0):

You are only storing it in local memory, once the page refreshes all that data will reset. You can store it in the cache or as a cookie if you just want to test what you have so far without setting up a database to store stuff from your table. you can store it in the cookie like this

```
document.cookie = itemID + '= { dateCompleted: ' + completed.toLocaleDateString() + ' }';
```